# Rubymine / Cucumber: Tests run fine, but are shown as “Failed to start” in Event Log

Tags: selenium, cucumber, rubymine

I have several Cucumber tests that are running fine (I closely watch them), all pass, and everything works good. But Event Log in Rubymine keeps showing all the tests that pass in this way:

```
Failed to start: 0 passed, 19 not started
```

Besides, the Run tab (which shows all tests as Passed) also says this after (otherwise successful) run:

```
Done: Scenarios 0 of 19
```

Can someone please help me understand why could it happen?

Screenshot:

[image]

*My setup:* Rubymine / Ruby / Selenium / Cucumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently it is a bug that exists in the current release build.
I contacted them, and they said it is related to [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17541).
They fixed it in [EAP build 145.184.8](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Early+Access+Program).
I was able to confirm the fix after I installed that build.